# How to create UITableViewCell like iphone Contact Address Cell?

Tags: iphone, layout, uitableview

I need help figuring out how to create a cell like the one representing an Address in the iphone Contacts app.  I'm not looking to create an address.  I just need to know how to show the following in edit mode:

1. Text on the left (like UITableViewCellStyleValue2)
2. Gray line separating the left and the right
3. Content on the right hand in a custom format--I will have varying formats depending on what I'm trying to present here, with differing heights.

Any sample code, Apple examples (though I can't find one), tutorials, or general guidances is greatly appreciated.  I'm trying to avoid having to create a custom container class to handle everything on the left and dynamically resize based on the content I want to put on the right. Surely someone has done this already, right?  :)

The edit mode looks like this: [image: Contacts Address Edit]

Comment: Can you shard your idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create your own UITableVIewCellSubclass, this is not as difficult as you might think.

Basically you just have to add 2 UITextField and a UIImageView in between for the separator.

I advise you to have a look at Apple's TableView Programming guide, and especially [A Closer Look at Table-View Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7)

You have a code sample very similar to what you are trying to achieve. Here is the idea (untested code) :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageOnRightCell";

    UITextField*main, *second;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

        main = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 220.0, 15.0)] autorelease];
        main.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:main];

        second = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220.0, 0.0, 220.0, 15.0)] autorelease];
        second.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:second];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: Yeah, I've subclassed a number of cells in another project. I was afraid I would have to go that route here, but was hoping someone would have already done the extra work.  ;)  I have not done the auto resizing so that's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I just did something like this. My solution was fairly specific to my data, but in general this is how I did it:

1. Left hand side text is a vertically centered UILabel
2. Right hand side is a UITableView
3. "123 Fake Street" would go into a UITableViewCell subclass that has a UITextField thrown into the content view.
4. "My City" and "ST" would go into a single UITableViewCell subclass that has to UITextField's thrown in. I actually did a UITextFieldSubclass that give me control over which borders to draw (i.e. drawLeftBorder = YES).
5. You have to decide when to resize, but you basically add the row in the right hand side and then call a begin/endUpdates block on the parent tableview. Be sure that the parent tableview implements heightForRowAtIndexPath and returns the correct value based on the data.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using a table view. Makes sense if you need that fine of control. I'm going to go the other route because I can reuse code from another project, but the table view idea is interesting.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: How do you handle the country, which in the screenshot shown in the question, is clickable and brings up another ViewController to select the country. Specifically, is what the user taps on a button, clickable label, clickable UIView or...?

Comment: It is a UITableView, so in the delegate just implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.